# How can I get System variable value in Java?

Tags: java, environment-variables

How can I get the System Variable value which is present in

```
MyComputer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables
```

in Java?

*Edit*

I have used `System.getenv()` method.

It is printing value if I give

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"));
```

and it is showing `null` value if I try the same for system variable created by me

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("DBE"));
```

Comment: You can try to restart the requesting process (NetBeans in my case).

Comment: I have observed that the restart option from eclipse doesn't work. Just close the application, and start it again.

Comment: Restarting IntelliJ solved my problem.

Comment: Restarting the system worked for me, may be JVM keeps cache of values at first start due to which new variables are not detected.

Comment: looks like DBE value is not exported

Answer (score 263):

Use the [`System.getenv(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-) method, passing the name of the variable to read.

Answer (score 59):

To clarify, system variables are the same as environment variables. User environment variables are set per user and are different whenever a different user logs in. System wide environment variables are the same no matter what user logs on.

To access either the current value of a system wide variable or a user variable in Java, see below:

```
String javaHome = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
```

For more information on environment variables see this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Also make sure the environment variable you are trying to read is properly set before invoking Java by doing a:

```
echo %MYENVVAR%
```

You should see the value of the environment variable. If not, you may need to reopen the shell (DOS) or log off and log back on.

Comment: Hi.. I have used System.getenv() method.. Itsprinting value if i give "System.out.println(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"));" and its showing null value if i give system variable created by me ("System.out.println(System.getenv("DBE"));"

Comment: `getenv` should be in small case instead of `getEnv` right?

Comment: If I do `echo %var%` it prints `%var%`. If I try instead `echo $var` it works and displays the value of that env variable. My `getenv` is returning null.

Comment: @dialex `%var%` used for windows, `$var` for unix / linux / MacOS systems.

Answer (score 34):

Actually the variable can be set or not, so, In Java 8 or superior its nullable value should be wrapped into an `Optional` object, which allows really good features. In the following example we gonna try to obtain the variable `ENV_VAR1`, if it doesnt exist we may throw some custom Exception to alert about it:

```
String ENV_VAR1 = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("ENV_VAR1")).orElseThrow(
  () -> new CustomException("ENV_VAR1 is not set in the environment"));
```

Answer (score 31):

There are a few details of interest when getting system/environment properties.

First, `System.getenv(String)` was introduced way-back-when, then deprecated. The deprecation (foolishly, IHMO) continued [all the way into JSE 1.4](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)).

It got [re-introduced in JSE 5](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)).

Those are set using the Environment Variables panel in Windows. Changes to the variables may not get picked up until your current VM is shutdown, and the CMD.exe instance is exited.

In contrast to the environment properties, Java also has Java system properties, accessible through [`System.getProperties()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()). These variables can be initialized when the VM is started using a series `-Dname=value` command line arguments. For example, the values for the properties `maxInMemory` and `pagingDirectory` are set in the command below:

```
C:\> java.exe -DmaxInMemory=100M -DpagingDirectory=c:\temp -jar myApp.jar
```

These properties can be modified at runtime, barring security policy restrictions.

Answer (score 6):

Google says to check out [getenv()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()):

> Returns an unmodifiable string map view of the current system environment.

I'm not sure how system variables differ from environment variables, however, so if you could clarify I could help out more.

Comment: I think raja means "system-wide" as opposed to "per-user" environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried rebooting since you set the environment variable?

It appears that Windows keeps it's environment variable in some sort of cache, and rebooting is one method to refresh it. I'm not sure but there may be a different method, but if you are not going to be changing your variable value too often this may be good enough.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by sombody above, restarting eclipse worked for me for the user defined environment variable.
After I restart eclipse IDE, `System.getenv()` is picking up my environment variable.

Comment: Yeah But why? is there a way to read the updated env variables without restarting eclipse / vscode ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you on a linux system?  If so be sure you are exporting your variable.

```
myVar=testvalue; export myVar
```

I get null unless I use export to define the value globally.

Answer (score 1):

This code gives you a map of Environment variables' names and the corresponding values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Map<String, String> map = System.getenv();
            System.out.println(map);
        }
```