# Environment Variable with Maven

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

I've ported a project from Eclipse to Maven and I need to set an environment variable to make my project work.

In Eclipse, I go to "Run -> Run configurations" and, under the tab "environment", I set "WSNSHELL_HOME" to the value "conf".

How can I do this with `Maven`?

Comment: I would suggest to get your project running without environment variable. And then move to maven.

Comment: There is no reason to skip the usage of environment variables if it is useful for your system and I am quite sure my solution works (I use it myself). See my hint refarding 'System.getenv'/'System.getProperty'.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can just pass it on the command line, as

```
mvn -DmyVariable=someValue install
```

**[Update]** Note that the order of parameters is significant - you need to specify any options *before* the command(s).**[/Update]**

Within the POM file, you may refer to system variables (specified on the command line, or in the pom) as `${myVariable}`, and environment variables as `${env.myVariable}`. *(Thanks to commenters for the correction.)*

#### Update2

OK, so you want to pass your system variable to your tests. If - as I assume - you use the [Surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) for testing, the best is to specify the needed system variable(s) within the pom, in your `plugins` section, e.g.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
            <configuration>
                ...
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <WSNSHELL_HOME>conf</WSNSHELL_HOME>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I need to launch 'mvn test', it doesn't seems to work, cause if I write mvn test -DWSNSHELL_HOME=conf I still get the exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/wsnshell.conf (No such file or directory)

Comment: @Janky, try it the other way around, i.e. `mvn -DWSNSHELL_HOME=conf test`.

Comment: nope... :( I still get java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/wsnshell.conf (No such file or directory)... in the code I read the variable in this way.. `System.getenv("WSNSHELL_HOME");` is it correct?

Comment: @Janky, wait a minute, do you run the app directly from the Maven build, or ...?

Comment: @Péter Török I admit that I'm a total noob with maven... here is what I've done so far... I've converted an eclipse project to maven with IAM plugin.. now I'm tring to execute the tests I've written with `mvn test` but i've got this problem... should I launch some command before mvn test? should I edit the pom? Thanks a million!

Comment: I think I will remove the environment variable... cause it still doesn't work. Thank you very much for your help indeed!!!

Comment: You two are confusing Environment Variables with System Properties. The -D command option sets System Properties only.

Comment: ${env.myVariable} does not seem to work.  I think it is not setting an environment variable.

Comment: @JoseMartinez, of course it is not setting it, who said it did? Maven is only reading the variable/property's current value, which you must set yourself (or pass on the command line).

Comment: @PéterTörök Dude -DmyVariable=someValue this is not setting the env variable.  I can tell because ${env.myVariable} does not work.  But -DmyVariable=someValue does set the "system property", and that I can tell because ${myVariable} works.

Comment: @JoseMartinez, I see, you are right with that. My fault, thanks for the clarification. I corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: If the  options should be specified before the command, why does `mvn clean install -DskipTests` work ? Shouldn't it be `mvn -DskipTests clean install`

Comment: I realize if variable is not in certain format it throws lifecycle error. example: `mvn clean test -Denable.it=true`

Comment: I had to set up file encdoing for unit tests. Solution of *Update 2* works for me:
`<file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>`.

Comment: @PéterTörök Hi. Is it possible to setUp Environment Variables or System Properties via maven not only for test but for Runtime?

Answer (score 35):

The `-D` properties will not be reliable propagated from the surefire-pluging to your test (I do not know why it works with eclipse). When using maven on the command line use the [argLine](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine) property to wrap your property. This will pass them to your test

```
mvn -DargLine="-DWSNSHELL_HOME=conf" test
```

Use `System.getProperty` to read the value in your code. Have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531694/how-can-i-get-system-variable-value-in-java/536150#536150) post about the difference of `System.getenv` and `Sytem.getProperty`.

Comment: You should read the property with System.getProperty("WSNSHELL_HOME") instead of using System.getenv.

Comment: Perfect, after spending A LOT of time trying other things, this one worked for me.

Comment: If you have configured argLine parameters for the surefire plugin in your pom.xml, then add the `${argLine}` placeholder, otherwise the parameters from the command line will not be picked up.
Example: `<argLine>-Duser.timezone=UTC ${argLine}</argLine>`

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! What a neat tool to configure sys-props for maven tests. Still at the first glance, it is very confusing, why it cannot use them directly, but requires an extra argument.

Answer (score 26):

You could wrap your maven command in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export YOUR_VAR=thevalue
mvn test
unset YOUR_VAR
```

Comment: Unbelievably, this is the only method that completely worked for me using the Surefire plugin.  Out of the 10 or so env vars I set in the POM, two of them are not seen when the test run.  Even if I set them in the shell and then `mvn install`, they are still somehow obscured.  However, if I run from a shell script, it works fine!  I wish I understood why this happens.

Comment: I believe this should be an accepted answer since this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 15):

For environment variable in Maven, you can set below.

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#environmentVariables
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#environmentVariables

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            ...
        </includes>
        <environmentVariables>
            <WSNSHELL_HOME>conf</WSNSHELL_HOME>
        </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 7):

Another solution would be to set `MAVEN_OPTS` (or other environment variables) in `${user.home}/.mavenrc` (or `%HOME%\mavenrc_pre.bat` on windows).

Since Maven 3.3.1 there are [new possibilities to set mvn command line parameters](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html), if this is what you actually want:

- `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/maven.config`
- `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/jvm.config`

Answer (score 4):

There is a maven plugin called [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html) this one provides a goal `set-system-properties` to set system variables. This is especially useful if you have a file containing all these properties. So you're able to read a property file and set them as system variable.

Answer (score 1):

in your code add:

`System.getProperty("WSNSHELL_HOME")`

Modify or add value property from maven command:

```
mvn clean test -DargLine=-DWSNSHELL_HOME=yourvalue
```

If you want to run it in Eclipse, add VM arguments in your Debug/Run configurations

- Go to Run -> Run configurations
- Select Tab Arguments
- Add in section VM Arguments

> -DWSNSHELL_HOME=yourvalue

[image: See image example]

you don't need to modify the POM

Answer (score 1):

You can pass some of the arguments through the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` variable.

For example, define a variable for maven proxy flags like this:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=$http_proxy_host -Dhttp.proxyPort=$http_proxy_port -Dhttps.proxyHost=$https_proxy_host -Dhttps.proxyPort=$http_proxy_port"
```

And then use `mvn clean install` (it will automatically pick up `_JAVA_OPTIONS`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the amazing tool [direnv](https://direnv.net/). With it you can inject environment variables once you cd into the project. These steps worked for me:

.envrc file

```
source_up
dotenv
```

.env file

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-DYourEnvHere=123"
```

Answer (score -1):

As someone might end up here changing his global Java options, I want to say defining **_JAVA_OPTIONS** is a bad idea. Instead define **MAVEN_OPTS** environment variable which will still be picked up automatically by Maven but it won't override everything like _JAVA_OPTS will do (e.g. IDE vm options).

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-DmyVariable=someValue"
```