# Jenkins Maven project environment variables

Tags: maven, jenkins, workspace

Im trying to build a project that has dependency on another project in Jenkins. It uses an environment variable in the POM to point to the right jars. So, basically, I need to set an environment variable for one project to point to the workspace of another one. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: if your second project is a dependency of the first one, running `mvn install`on the second should allow the first one to find the required jar on the local(jenkins) repository

Answer (score 0):

An answer: [Environment Variable with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510690/environment-variable-with-maven)

Anyway, if your goal is to compile your maven project including other project libraries, i would recommend better to install your other project jars with `mvn install-file ...` and the rely on repository dependencies instead of external jars. See http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

Comment: Let me rephrase the question a little bit - I can set environment variables just fine by checking "Inject environment variables to the build process" under "Build environment" and typing something like "MY_LIB_PATH = ${WORKSPACE}" But in this case Im setting my lib path to the workspace of the current project. So, naturally, the dependencies will not resolve. How would I set it to another project's workspace?

Comment: You can customize each job workspace as environment variables or system properties in jenkins. Then, you can make references to these variables in your jobs.