# Integrating BIRT report in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, birt

I am trying to integrate BIRT reports into my existing spring boot application with the help of [BIRT in spring boot app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069938/birt-in-spring-boot-app) but I am using maven. when I add the dependency to BIRT 4.6.0-20160607 it was giving

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes"

and when I change dependency to 4.5.0a it was giving

> Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]

kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class}) in BirtReportRunnerApphlication...

Comment: It is giving compile time error: "cannot find symbol MongoAutoConfiguration.class"

Comment: Thanks @Max Zonov : I've been struggling to have my Spring Boot Standalone application work with BIRT report engine and Postgres. I kept getting errors like "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path" . Even though my app is configured to work with Postgres. Your tip solved my problems! Thank you very much.