# maven-surefire-plugin system properties and eclipse integration?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I set system properties for the surefire execution in maven's pom.xml. Eclipse ignores those. Is there any way to fix that issue?

In particular I use the basedir property to determine file locations, ie the build directory etc.

I don't want to run the tests as "maven test" because that's slow.

### Update

I'm now using the test class' resource location to determine the project location on disk:

https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/misc/blob/master/env-utils/src/main/java/com/github/jjYBdx4IL/utils/env/Maven.java#L64

This requires no configuration **at all**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jjYBdx4IL.utils</groupId>
    <artifactId>env-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from what you're saying, when you run maven at the command line, you've got environment variables set, which maven picks up. If this is the case, then [either passing it along on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510690/environment-variable-with-maven) or [setting the system properties](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) seem like it might be the solution that you're looking for. The other thing is, make sure you're using "project.basedir", not just "basedir". See 
[here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+Properties+Guide) for the property names

Comment: that works if I run the tests as maven tests only. But running tests in that way is slow.