# How to use environnement variables inside a Robot framework script

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I want to use the environnement variables provided by jenkins (like `Build_Id`) as part of my robot script.
For eg:

```
user = "abc" + Build_Id
```

This is so that I can match my variable/value to a particular build.

Is there a way to use the env variables inside a Robot script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can [pass command line options as described here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-command-line-options).

So, if you start RF via Jenkins shell execution do something like this:

```
robot --variable Build_Id:$Build_Id path/to/tests/
```

If you start RF indirectly by calling a script or maven or ant build script, you have to pass the variables accordingly (here is an [example for maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510690/environment-variable-with-maven)).

Answer (score 3):

You can easily access environment variables, in fact they [are available in the cases/keywords scope just like a normal user-defined variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html)

```
${my var}=    Set Variable    abc %{BUILD_ID}
```

Note the access char is `%`, not `$` as is for the user variables.

You can also use the keyword [Get Environment Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Get%20Environment%20Variable) from the OperatingSystem library, which allows to have a default value if the env variable is not present, or fail the case/keyword.