# How to read in java, a variable which is declared in unix

Tags: java, unix

i have a variable in unix, i want to pass the value of that variable to java code, so that i can use in java. One way is using properties file. Is there any other way around..??

Comment: You can pass the Unix variable as command line argument to your Java code.

Answer (score 1):

You [System#getenv](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) to either get the entire environment or a single environment variable

Comment: While correct, it would be nice if you could link to a more up-to-date reference, Java 1.5 is a little old now ;)

Comment: Depends on how backward compatible are you, Changed it to 6 :)

Comment: Well, technically, Java 7 is (backwards compatible), but it also allows developers to see if methods have become deprecated or if it is suggest that a better method is now available.  It's a nit pick I know, but I've seen down-votes for less :P

Comment: ok that's a good reason (the deprecation), although still, when you write code others might run in another JVM, 7 is not a good idea yet.

Answer (score 1):

`public static String getenv(String name)`

used to The preferred way to extract system-dependent information is the system properties of the java.lang.System.getProperty methods and the corresponding getTypeName methods of the Boolean, Integer, and Long primitive types. For example:

`String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path",".");`

[LEARN HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29)

A similar Question is [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531694/how-can-i-get-system-variable-value-in-java) , also a good discussion [here](http://quirkygba.blogspot.in/2009/11/setting-environment-variables-in-java.html).

Comment: `Also consider suggested by Mr. anubhava`

Answer (score 0):

The variables have different Endianness.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

As far as I can remember the endianness of data in the JVM was represented in Big-Endian and in Unix it was in Little-Endian.

You should convert it using Bytebuffer or just do it manually :P