# Not able to read value from environment variable

Tags: java

I have added one environment variable manually in windows 7
and i am getting null while I am trying to get it from java program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   System.out.println(System.getenv("name"));

}
```

I am using java 1.7

Comment: If you aren't sure when the environment variable will be "active", then restart your computer, to make sure that Java won't use the old values.

Answer (score 2):

to answer your own question try this :

```
System.out.println(System.getenv());
```

then you should be able to see all the set values in environment.

for example if you are trying to get **user home**, the property you are looking for is :

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("HOMEPATH"));
```

you may want to check the properties as well, it could be the case that you added something to the properties

```
System.out.println(System.getProperties());
```

also this link might be a use for you:

[How can I get System variable value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531694/how-can-i-get-system-variable-value-in-java)