# Calling JDK terminal utilities in an OS agnostic manner?

Tags: java, operating-system

Does anyone have an idea on how to call something from JDK_INSTALL_FIR/bin using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
```

Without having to care about OS terminal specifics like escaping or quoting spaces in paths on Windows or concatenating `.exe` at the end of the command.

In other words I want to make this work on Windows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java -version")
```

I'm open to any solutions like bundling my own JDK, or generally anything that will save me from checking what OS I'm currently running on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Java path is saved in system variables (mostly)
try something like:

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"));
```

Which should return path to java (not sure about `"JAVA-HOME"` )
It is from:
[How can I get System variable value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531694/how-can-i-get-system-variable-value-in-java)

---

Generally I advice using:

```
System.getenv(String);
```

method:
[getenv documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String))