# Fetching username from windows logged in? for my swing application

Tags: java, swing

I Need to fetch the username from windows and i need to assign that username for my swing application and how can i do that.
Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.event.*;  
public class PasswordFieldExample {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    JFrame f=new JFrame("User-ID");    
     final JLabel label = new JLabel();            
     label.setBounds(20,150, 200,50);  

     JLabel l1=new JLabel("Username:");    
        l1.setBounds(20,20, 80,30);    
        JButton b = new JButton("Login");  
        b.setBounds(100,120, 80,30);    
        final JTextField text = new JTextField();  
        text.setBounds(100,20, 100,30);    
               f.add(l1); f.add(label); f.add(b); f.add(text);  
                f.setSize(300,300);    
                f.setLayout(null);    
                f.setVisible(true);     
                b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {       
                   String data = "Username " + text.getText();
                   label.setText(data);          
                }  
             });   
}  
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531694/how-can-i-get-system-variable-value-in-java

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990038/how-to-get-windows-username-in-java

Comment: I just want to set my username from windows logged in,how can i set that thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final JTextField text = new JTextField(); 
text.setText(System.getProperty("user.name")); 
text.setBounds(100, 20, 100, 30);
```

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). ..

Comment: .. 3) In this case, the size of a text field should be suggested by the number of columns of text it is meant to display, as well as the details of the font of the field (the larger the font, that larger the field. E.G. `JTextField text = new JTextField();` should be `JTextField text = new JTextField(12);` for a field meant to display 12 characters. Meanwhile the **location** of the field is best arranged logically (as opposed to hard coded values) using the layout, layout constraints and borders and margins applied to the field.

Comment: @AndrewThompson.. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Vasanth Please mark your answer as accepted, since it solves the problem completely. You can find a tick mark below the down arrow button

Comment: I cant find that tick mark under your answer

Comment: actually u made the answer in comment section i think so.. just check it tsk

Comment: while i m trying to click the tick and i m getting the reply as " u cant accept ur own answer for two days"

Answer (score 4):

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

This might help

Comment: @TSK.But how can i assign that above statement

Comment: @TSK..will you please integrate that statement with my code

Comment: I don't get you. Where do you want to set this value in your swing?

Comment: in my username textbox @TSK

Comment: `final JTextField text = new JTextField();
text.setText(System.getProperty("user.name"));
text.setBounds(100, 20, 100, 30);`

Is it ok?

Comment: let me check@TSK.. Thank you very much..

Comment: ya.. everything is fine right now thanks tsk

Comment: Thank you. Accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)