# Using Background title as Background in cucumber

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

Let's say I use Background feature which has the below steps:

```
Background: My pre-requisites
Given Step one
When Step Two
Then Step Three
....
Then Step Fifteen
```

So basically my Background has 15 common steps that is required for a set of scenario to run.

My question is : Is it possible to use the Background title `My pre-requisites` in other feature files, instead of writing down all the 15 steps as Background? Or is there any other way to handle this more gracefully.

Comment: You can create a before hook to code the background logic and reuse it across any feature file. Even tag the hook so u can filter out scenarios where u do not want the before hook to run...

Comment: That makes sense and looks clean. Give it as answer so that i can close this.

Comment: You need to differentiate between things you need to do to run any test at all against your application vs things you are automating in you application to get it to a stage where you can perform your test.

The first might be something like pre-loading a set of data.

The second would be logging into the application and navigating to certain pages

Which are you talking about?

Comment: The second scenario, where I need to set up few things for my test to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a before hook to code the background logic and reuse it across any feature file. Even tag the hook so u can filter out scenarios where u do not want the before hook to run.

Answer (score 1):

Alongside the existing answer, you could also write a new step that compresses the functionality of the 15 steps into one or two steps that express what you are setting up.

The questions revolving around it are these:

Does the business need to know how the user will interact with the site to get to the point where you are ready to begin the test?

Can you bypass how the user will interact with the site to get there without information surrounding the test getting lost in translation between the dev team and the business?

For the former, I would go with a Background. The latter, I would go with a Hook.

For example:

- I need to register a user in order to log in as them in my test. The Givens will start at me logging in, so I'll register the user through an API in a Hook.
- I need to register a user in order to test the functionality of a new user on exiting the form, and various items surrounding registration, so I'll register the user, starting with some Background steps.